# How to convert arraylist to string in groovy script?

Tags: groovy

How to convert list to string in groovy ? My arraylist return values like [410657e6-2655-423c-b7b8-599177daa830].

This is only one value in the list. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a List of Strings, with only one element in the list, you can simply do:

```
String value = list[0]
```